# What is the concept of a software product which is created based on another?

Tags: word-request

I know mash-up, which is the hybrid of more than one applications, and third-party which is run as add-on acting as a component, but what I mean is not them, rather a product or application created based on one, not necessarily more, service like Wiki and Linux and that can be run independently, correspondingly, like Wikipedia and Ubuntu.

Also, Edubuntu, an other operating system built based on Ubuntu for some particular reasons and purposes. And so on.

If any, can you tell me the exact jargon which can cover those software originated from one product like Linux kernel forming an "ecological chain" surronding their origination?

Comment: I think a common term for this is *derivatives*.

Comment: @DamkerngT. Any phrase containing 'surround'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Derivative* would be the exact term for that.

> **[derivative](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/derivative_1)**
>   <sup>noun [countable]</sup>
>   something that has developed or been obtained from something else)

There are a lot of examples of *derivative* on the web, e.g. [Derivatives - Debian Wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/Derivatives), [List of Linux distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Linux_distributions) on Wikipedia. Here is an example on the Wikipedia page:

> Kubuntu: An official **derivative** of Ubuntu Linux using KDE instead of the GNOME or Unity interfaces used by default in Ubuntu.
>   <sub>(emphasis mine)</sub>

Another possible term is *fork*, which is intended to be the same product with changes, rather than a different product. (Special thanks go to [ArtOfCode](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/121520) on Open Source.SE who suggested this term.)

I couldn't come up with any term that includes or is related to *"surround"*.